# Dynamically increase the memory of Java programs

Tags: java, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting JVM heap size at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763295/setting-jvm-heap-size-at-runtime)

Is it possible to prevent a program from crashing when it encounters a `OutOfMemoryError` by increasing the memory allowed to the program?
Can it be done at run time?

### Reason for increasing the memory

I was talking a  lot of screen shots using `java.awt.Robot` and after some time my Vector ran out of memory. At 60 `BufferedImage`  it was out.
so 1280 x 800 resolution, 3 byte RGB `BufferedImage` and 60 images later, the vector was out.
So I guess the memory consumed was
1280 x 800 x 60 x 3 = **do the math** bytes

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472593/can-the-jvm-max-heap-size-be-dynamic

Comment: Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Which ?:)

Comment: `Can it be done at run time?` No - or at least - not by you, even if you could, eventually you're going to hit a hard limit...

Comment: @Mark I never thought of that.. I will elaborate further in an edit what I meant

Comment: for those who wonder its 184320000 byte (btw you would be interested with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to think of other solutions other than dynamically changing memory size including

- allocating a reasonable amount of memory to start with.
- decreasing the resolution of your captured images (which is what I did for a similar problem by decreasing image size)
- caching your images to disk when not immediately needed vs. a combination.

Comment: I overcame that by directly encoding the images to a video and writing them to the disk. :)

Comment: to be more specific, I used `Xuggler` API and it has a `IMediaWriter` that transcodes the data and writes it to the disk as a video. All you need to do is supply an extension. It will do the rest

Comment: I was going over your profile and I saw that you use AutoIt. I have to study it as apart of my course. Is it really used a lot in day-to-day affairs?

Comment: @LittleChild: I don't know AutoIt's usage statistics, but it is quite a handy little tool that can be used in many ways and for many purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - No.  Or at least, not with Hotspot JVMs.

References:

- [Setting JVM heap size at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763295/setting-jvm-heap-size-at-runtime)
- [Why do we have to increase the Java Heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852781/why-do-we-have-to-increase-the-java-heap) ... which has answers that explain why there is no simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

Ok well you can't actually increase the heapsize, but you could spawn another process with a new heapsize.
Have a play with this:

```
 public class SpawnAndChangeHeap {
     public static void main(String[] args){  

         //Get the jvm heap size.  
        long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "" + heapSize );  

    if(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("-spawn")) {

        try {
            Process proc;
                proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c java -Xms32m -Xmx128m SpawnAndChangeHeap /n");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("something went wrong");  }
    }
    System.exit(0);


     }  
}
```

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783086/is-there-a-way-to-increase-java-heap-space-in-the-code-itself/13783276#13783276) which uses the more robust `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

> I was talking a lot of screen shots using `java.awt.Robot` and after some time my `Vector` ran out of memory.

Don't put them in a `Vector`.  There is no need to store them in memory at all.

Instead save each image to either of:

1. A Zip archive (this gets around creating '1000s of files' - which is itself problematic) with no compression (zip compression does nothing good for images).
2. A video stream (pointing to a file).  See the Movie Maker of the [Monte Media Library](http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/) for a JMF based version that works quite well.

Comment: Xuggler did the trick for me. I even had a look at Monte. But the code is a `horrible mess` according to Randelschofer himself.